# How to set value in application state and use any where in project in wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to set a value in application state in wpf and want to use the set value in whole application where i want.i am using below code for it but i am getting below error
**"The given key was not present in the dictionary."**

```
public static class ApplicationState
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, object> _values =
                   new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public static void SetValue(string key, object value)
        {
            _values.Add(key, value);
        }

        public static T GetValue<T>(string value)
        {
            return (T)_values["value"];
        }
    }
```

Here i am setting value in application state

```
 ApplicationState.SetValue("ProjectID", pid);
```

here i am getting error while getting application stat value

```
  var id= ApplicationState.GetValue<string>("ProjectID");
```

Comment: Why are you passing the literal key `"value"` in your `GetValue` method rather than the value of the parameter `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pid must be string otherwise it won't work.
As Mapper said, change GetValue body to

```
return (T)_values[value];
```